# Function is not looping the required amount of times

Tags: python, loops, python-3.x, win32com

In the code I've written, there's a variable called SignA. Depending upon this value the loop needs to repeat a certain amount of times. In the case of this example lets say SignA is 3 and hence the inner contents needs to loop three times.

Here's the code:

```
 if (signA > 0):
    count = 0
    for iterate in range(signA):
        count=count + 1
        #ws.Cells(row_origin, column_origin).Value = "Created " + str(signA) + " Sign A signs"
        # The index pertains to the index location of the element in the list
        # the 'n' represents the actual name of the header attribute
        #for test in range(signA):
        repeated = 0
        for index, n in enumerate(header):
            rowDictionary[n] = row[index+3]
            ws.Cells(row_origin, column_origin).Value = rowDictionary[n]


            column_origin += 1
            print("The value of signa is: " + str(signA))
            repeated+=1
        print("Loop has repeated {} times".format(str(repeated)))
        print("count (this increments to the sign num value): " + str(count))
        #print("The row_origin is: " + str(row_origin) + " and the column_origin is: " + str(column_origin))
        #row_origin = row_origin + 1
        #resetRowDictionaryionary()
    print("Ending row loop now. This is printed once the whole sign num loops are done")
```

I require the inner loop of line "for index, n in enumerate(header):" to repeat 3 times, however it appears to only repeat once and then not print anything at all.

Can someone please take a look at my code.

Thanks!

Comment: By the way, to add more context, I'm eseentially printing out a string onto each new row, being read from a csv file of 25 column items seperated by a comma delimiter. The contents of rowDictionary for one of the rows in the csv file is "3,0,0,471,SIGN,1/01/1902,,-33.82507,151.02038,SZ,R4-230,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,". I'm essentially looping through each item in this string once and printing it out to an excel file. If SignA is > 1 then it needs to print this line out x number of times onto a new row in the excel file.

Comment: Just some quick idea: maybe you swapped the variables at the enumerate-function by accident. ```list(enumerate(['a', 'b', 'c']))``` results in ```[(0, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (2, 'c')]```

Comment: Thanks, but I already managed to solve the problem! ;-)